# Multiple instances of SlideToggle which toggle everything

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have the following script which appears multiple times on my page.  I have a simple slide toggle attached to `<div class="info">` and contolled by `<a rel="viewinfo">` tag, but when I click on the anchor, all the divs with class info slide.

here is the HTML/PHP

```
<div class="couplistMeta">
    <a class='view' rel="viewinfo" href="#">View Coupon</a>
    <a class="print" href="#">Print</a>
</div>
<div class="info">
    <p><?php echo $rec2[4]."&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;&nbsp;Phone:&nbsp;&nbsp;".$rec2['phone']; ?></p><p><?php echo $rec2['address']."&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;&nbsp;".$rec2['city'].",&nbsp;".$rec2['state']."&nbsp;".$rec2['zip']; ?></p>
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.info').hide();
    $("a[rel='viewinfo']").click(function() {
            $('div.info').slideToggle(400);
            return false;
    });
});
```

I tried using `$(this).next('div.info').slideToggle(400);` but this just broke the effect.  So `$('div.info')` is too general, how can I be more specific with the JS?

Comment: What JS framework are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.info').hide();
    $("a[rel='viewinfo']").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().next('.info').slideToggle(400);
        return false;
    });
});
```

The issue being due to `$('div.info')` implicitly iterating over all `div` elements with the class `info` on the page.